# Can I use my own Certificate Authority for HTTPS over LAN?

Tags: ssl, https, certificate, client-certificates, ca

I have a server and a few clients, all running on different docker containers. The users can use the client by entering localhost:3000 on their browser (where the client docker is running).
All the containers run on the same LAN. I want to use HTTPS.
Can I sign a public private key pair using my own CA, then load the CA's public key to the browser?
I want to use the normal flow for public domains, but internally with my own CA.
Or should I look for another solution?

Comment: 1. You can use your own CA at the server if all the clients trust it. 2. You don't sign key pairs, you sign certificates. 3. 'Load the CA's public key to the browser' is meaningless. The browser needs to trust the CA's *certificate.*

Comment: @user207421 3 - How can the browser trust the CA's certificate if it's my own CA? I need a way to give the browser the public key of the CA so it will have it in addition to the list of CAs the browser already know, no?

Comment: No, you need a way to give the browser the CA's *certificate.* I already said that. You could rely on the user deciding to accept the certificate when prompted, or you could preload the CA certificate into the browser's or operating system's trust store, whichever is appropriate.

Comment: @user207421 OK now I see what you meant in the first comment more clearly. So when we say CA, actually all I need is a certificate, or I need a running server that holds the CA's private key and does things?

Comment: A CA is essentially a private key and a corresponding certificate with signing authority, so that `openssl` or whatever tool you're using can sign other certificates with it. I don't understand the part of your question after 'or I need'. You will always need a running server.

Comment: @user207421 I'm just not sure about the whole flow and what I need. For a public domain, I issue a certificate from a known CA, I add it to my server and it works. Here when I don't want to use a public CA, I'm not completely sure what I should do. Should I take a key pair, make a certificate from the public key, load it on the client's system, load the private key to the server, and that's it? I guess I missed things.

Comment: You haven't even told us what system and what tools you're using. Too broad and off topic.

Comment: @user207421 We're using Linux on Docker, The client browser runs on Windows (Firefox/Chrome). The client makes a call to a node server that calls different python servers, then sends the response to the client.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Meta: since you've now disclosed nodejs, that makes it at least borderline for topicality.

In general, the way PKIX (as used in SSL/TLS including HTTPS) works is that the server must have a privatekey and matching certificate; this is the same whether you use a public CA or your own (as you desire). The server should also have any intermediate or 'chain' cert(s) needed to verify its cert; a public CA will *always* need such chain cert(s) because CABforum rules (codifying common best practice) prohibits issuing 'subscriber' (EE) certs directly from a root, while your own CA is up to you -- you can choose to use intermediate(s) or not, although as I say it is considered best practice to use them and keep the root privatekey 'offline' -- in cryptography, that means not on any system that communicates with anybody, such as in this case servers that request certificates, thus eliminating one avenue of attack -- on a specialized device that is 'airgapped' (not connected or even able to be connected to any network) and in a locked vault, possibly with 'tamper protection', a polite name for self-destruct. As a known example of the rigor needed to secure something as sensitive as the root key of an important CA, compare Stuxnet.

The client(s) does not need and should not be configured with the *server* cert unless you want to do pinning; it(they) *do* need the *CA* root cert. Most clients, and particularly browsers, already have many/most/all public CA root certs builtin, so using a cert from such a CA does not require any action on the client(s); OTOH using your own CA requires adding your CA cert to the client(s). Chrome on Windows uses the Microsoft-supplied (Windows) store; you can add to this explicitly (using the GUI dialog, or the certutil program or powershell), although in domain-managed environments (e.g. businesses) it is also popular to 'push' a CA cert (or certs) using GPO. Firefox by default uses its own truststore, which you must add to explicitly, but (although I was not aware in 2022 when I first wrote this answer) since about 2018 it has an option to also use the Windows truststore, and more recently the macOS 'keychain'.

In nodejs you configure the privatekey, server cert, and if needed chain cert(s), as [documented](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest/docs/api/tls.html#tlscreatesecurecontextoptions)

PS: note you generally should, and for Chrome (and new Edge, which is actually Chromium) *must*, have the SubjectAlternativeName (SAN) extension in the server cert specify its domain name(s), or optionally IP address(es), NOT (or not only) the CommonName (CN) attribute as you will find in many outdated and/or incompetent instructions and tutorials on the Web. Update: as of 2023 this is also a must for Firefox. OpenSSL commandline makes it easy to do CommonName but not quite so easy to do SAN; there are *many* Qs on several Stacks about this. Any public CA after about 2010 does SAN automatically.

Comment: "The server should also have any intermediate or 'chain' cert(s) needed to verify its cert" - What does that mean exactly? I thought the certificate issued by the CA, for example Google, is signed by the root, then by the CA. You're saying that it's not the case and there's another organization between the CA and the root?

Comment: Didn't get the intermediates part. Why can't I have my own CA that directly uses the root? Or why is it not as good as using intermediates?

Comment: You say that "they do need the CA root cert". Don't they (the clients) also need the cert of all intermediates and the cert of the CA?

Comment: "using your own CA requires adding your CA cert to the client" - So if I use public CA, the client needs only the root cert, and if I use my own CA, the client needs the CA cert (and not the root's)?

Comment: (1) yes, the intermediate or chain certs are between the server and the root, hence the name 'intermediate'. Using google is a bad example, because google has its _own_ intermediate -- thus a google server uses a server cert (for google) which is issued by an intermediate CA cert (also for google but different) which is issued by a public root CA cert, currently GlobalSign (but it has changed in the past and may change again). As I said, for your own CA you can choose to use intermediate(s) or not, but using one is best practice.

Comment: (2) standardly the server sends any needed intermediate(s) as part of the handshake. That's why I said the server needs to have it/them. For the same reason the client _doesn't_ need to have it/them. The client does need the root for _any_ CA, but for a public CA the client usually already _has_ the root, so you don't _change_ anything; for your own CA the client _doesn't_ already have your root and you need to add it.

Comment: Thanks! And why are the intermediates needed anyway?

Comment: What if I use a normal public domain and a known CA, then in the DNS records I have an A record that points to a local IP in my LAN, that should work?

Comment: (1) Using an intermediate is best practice because it allows the root key to be offline, and replacing an intermediate due to (potential) compromise or policy/practice change(s) is _much_ easier than replacing a root similarly. For public CAs it is _required_ because cabforum says so. (2) Yes, using a cert from a public CA for a domain name _that you own_, and pointing that domain to your internal system(s), either via public DNS, local 'split-horizon' DNS, or other resolution method(s), is one valid approach.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand what it means for the root key to be offline. I thought the browser already has the public key of the CA, then it gets a certificate from the server that is signed using that public key, and that's how it can read and validate it. By "offline" you mean that it was compromised and no longer trustable?

Comment: No; an offline root key is one not used to issue end-user certs which as a result can be better protected. See edit.